# How to send Windows key over VNC to Linux from Windows?

Tags: windows, linux, vnc

Alright, so I'm running Linux with AwesomeWM on my home machine. I'm running x11vnc on that machine and I want to connect to it from a windows machine. So it suffices to say that I need the Windows key for my home machine to function.

I really like TightVNC, but I have found that only RealVNC is able to send the Windows key presses that I need. My problem is that RealVNC is sorely lacking customization and I feel it's inferior to TightVNC and unusable.
I know that Ctrl-Esc sends the windows key press in Tight but then I can't use it as a modifier key. Useless.

Anyone have any ideas? I don't think it's a server issue since I've tried Tightvnc server on the linux machine and it still doesn't work, at least in TightVNC. It works with Real anyway.
Oh and UltraVNC doesn't work either.

Comment: I'm probably being slow here, but _why_ do you need the Windows key when controlling your Linux machine?

Comment: Have you checked the F8 menu in realvnc?

Comment: F8 doesn't have any more options than I get from the initial connection options.
The windows key I need for the WM I'm using. It's keyboard oriented and the main modifier key is the windows key.

Comment: At least with tigervnc (which is very similar to tightvnc) you can lock the ctrl and alt keys in the F8 menu. But not the windows key.

Answer (score 2):

Try using Fullscreen in TigerVNC (https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=177932)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. In my honest opinion I still think that I extracted all the essential parts from the link. Did you read the contents of the link?

Comment: The entire essential parts are not *Try using Fullscreen*. Answers consisting primarily of links to off-site resources are not appropriate here. The answer becomes useless if that off-site location is unavailable for some reason (moved, off-line, deleted, etc.), at which point the answer has zero value here. The response to that is not *Did you go to the other site and read the link?* - that just demonstrates the point we're making.

Comment: Feel free to answer and present the "entire essential parts" that you think I am missing instead of repeating what MariusMatutiae wrote.

Comment: The commenters here obviously did not read the link. "Enable fullscreen mode might work." is basically "Try using Fullscreen in TigerVNC". Nothing more, nothing less.